# How can a value inside a Ajax javascript code be manipulated by JSP code?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, servlets

Ok, this javascript code works perfectly

In `chat.jsp`, we got these

```
function handleReceiveChat() {
            if (receiveReq.readyState == 4) {
                var chat_div = document.getElementById('div_chat');
                var xmldoc = receiveReq.responseXML;
                var message_nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("message"); 
                var n_messages = message_nodes.length
                for (i = 0; i < n_messages; i++) {
                    var user_node = message_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("user");
                    var text_node = message_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("text");
                    var time_node = message_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("time");
                    chat_div.innerHTML += user_node[0].firstChild.nodeValue + '&nbsp;';
                    chat_div.innerHTML += '<font class="chat_time">' + time_node[0].firstChild.nodeValue + '</font><br />';
                    chat_div.innerHTML += text_node[0].firstChild.nodeValue + '<br />';
                    chat_div.scrollTop = chat_div.scrollHeight;
                    lastMessage = (message_nodes[i].getAttribute('id'));
                }
                mTimer = setTimeout('getChatText();',2000); //Refresh our chat in 2 seconds
            }
        }
```

The problem is that I want to decode `message_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("text");` using the `URLEncoder.decode`.

I want to do something like this `var text_node = "<%=URLEncoder.decode(%> message_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("text")<%)%>";` but eclipse said that it got `Syntax error on token ")", delete this token`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that because JavaScript is a client side, and Jsp is a server side.